# Restore a backup generated using backpack backup manager

Tags: laravel-backpack

is there a way to restore the backup from the backpack backup manager?
I have check the https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/BackupManager but i can not see an option to perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

That package is just an interface for *creating* backups using [spatie/laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup). It provides no interface for *restoring* backups - you'll have to do that manually, I'm afraid.